Why is my React Query request returning html instead of data?
I am trying to use a react query hook I made to make a request to mock data using json-server, but when the call is made it just returns an html document. I am trying to figure out what I did wrong, so any help would be appreciated. My code is below. I console logged the response also
Console logged response from hook call
clients:  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module">
import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh"
RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
</script>

    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>FlowSwift POC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx?t=1716566140428"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Hook file
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { api, queryClient } from "@/services/api";
import { ClientType } from "./types";

const endpoint = "client";
export const baseClientQueryKey = "client";

export const useGetClients = () =>
  useQuery<ClientType[]>({
    queryKey: [baseClientQueryKey],
    queryFn: async () => api.get(endpoint),
  });

API file
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryClient} from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export const baseURL ='http://localhost:5174';

export const baseHeaders = {};

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response.data
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

Mocks Data index.ts file
import axios from 'axios';
import { QueryClient} from '@tanstack/react-query';

export const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export const baseURL = Boolean(import.meta.env.VITE_MOCK) ? 'http://localhost:5174' : 'http://localhost:8098';

export const baseHeaders = {};

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response.data
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

Mocks Data index.cjs file
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const clientMock = require("./data/clientMock.json");

const serverPort = 5174;

/**
 *
 * @param {MockServerConfig} config
 *
 *
 * @throws {Error}
 */

export const startMockServer = () => {
  try {
    const mockServer = jsonServer.create();

    /* Add mock data entities here */

    const router = jsonServer.router({
      client: clientMock,
    });

    const middleware = jsonServer.defaults();

    mockServer.use(middleware);
    mockServer.use(
      jsonServer.rewriter({
        "/*": "/$1",
        "/client/:clientId": "/client?clientId=:clientId",
      })
    );

    mockServer.use(router);

    mockServer.listen(serverPort, () => {
      console.log(`JSON Server is running on http://localhost:${serverPort}/`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    } else {
      console.log("createMockServer failed", error);
    }
  }
};

startMockServer();

Client Mock Data
[
  {
    "clientId": "123",
    "clientName": "Client 1",
    "clientStatus": "LEAD"
  },
  {
    "clientId": "456",
    "clientName": "Client 2",
    "clientStatus": "CURRENT"
  },
  {
    "clientId": "789",
    "clientName": "Client 3",
    "clientStatus": "COLD"
  }
]

Component calling hook
import { useGetClients } from "@/services/client/clientServiceHooks";

export const ClientsTable = () => {
  const { data: clients } = useGetClients();

  console.log("clients: ", clients);
  return <div>ClientsTable</div>;
};


In your hook you're calling api.get(endpoint) which is just api.get("client")
